# Does NPM publish compress by default?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

As per the documentation `npm publish` accepts either a folder or tarball as argument. If a folder is the target, will `npm publish` and/or the target registry perform any kind of compression of the folder in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

`npm publish` delegates to [`pack.packDirectory`](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/latest/lib/pack.js#L107) in case of a directory as an argument, which uses the `npm-packlist` package and eventually [creates a tar](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/latest/lib/pack.js#L131).